# Rails3 MiniMagick load error on choose_processor

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, carrierwave, minimagick

A rails 3.2.13 application is running both on localhost and on server (in development mode).  In localhost the application loads an image via carrierwave and MiniMagick properly.

On the server, an error is raised

```
undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass
```

, with the full stack leading of as such:

```
mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:24:in `choose_processor'
mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick.rb:64:in `mogrify?'
mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick/image.rb:360:in `run_command'
mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick/image.rb:171:in `valid?'
mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick/image.rb:140:in `create'
mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick/image.rb:48:in `read'
mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick/image.rb:111:in `block in open'
mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick/image.rb:110:in `open'
mini_magick (3.7.0) lib/mini_magick/image.rb:110:in `open'
carrierwave (0.9.0) lib/carrierwave/processing/mini_magick.rb:260:in `manipulate!'
```

Other postings allude to the fact that it may be
[a miniMagick version issue](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1282).  But the localhost version is the same as the server's, as is carrierwave, rails, OSX...

Based on the module documentation, it appears that no processor is being picked up. Thus the installation may have gone awry.

This question is edited as maybe two issues are at hand: different versions of MiniMagick are spawning different behaviours.  Both are now separate questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in  Passenger v3, and the way it behaves on start-up with Apache. (Passenger 4 apparently does not have the issue)

The solution is the same in any case as per [this proposal](https://coderwall.com/p/tzhtzq) by editing end of development and/or production environment files with:

```
  ENV['PATH'] = "/usr/local/bin:#{ENV['PATH']}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Link your identify, convert and other to /usr/local/bin (or /usr/bin) and it will work.

```
$ which identify
/whatever/identify

$ sudo ln -s /whatever/identify /usr/local/bin

$ which identify
/usr/local/bin/identify
```

And you need to install:

```
gem 'mini_magick', '~> 3.5.0'
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm already there.  `$ which identify
/usr/local/bin/identify`   I assumed for a while that I had a symlink issue (which I still believe was valid as I needed a persistent uploads folder) and solved that in the meantime.  That symlinked folder now shows a tmp directory, but am still getting a "No such file or directory" error.  So is MiniMagick targetting a different area?

Comment: FWIW, the no file or directory error is happening with gem version 3.6.  I installed 3.7 and ran which identify and it is pointing to /usr/local/bin/identify. However the error generated is as initially: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass.  Not sure which path to beat now...

Comment: Oh, then you need to install `gem 'mini_magick', '~> 3.5.0'`, as they discussed on github

Comment: Unfortunately that leads to the same "No such file or directory" error.  why it runs locally and not on remote server is hard to explain.  One element could be in the passenger deployment.  Another is that apparently "MiniMagick uses tempfiles, but doesn't keep references to them.
That means they get deleted automatically when GarbageCollector is run".  but why locally it has them and not remotely?

Comment: The observation that tempfile references not being kept is an old one (2007).  I wonder whether it is still valid today.  But it makes sense, where locally time to load is insignificant and my connection to web is so-so;  for an 800kb file, failure may have it's explanation.  Is there a timeout figure on keeping the reference? any way to work around this?